# How to give permissions to xamarin camera

Tags: android, forms, xamarin, permissions, camera

I wanted to add camera to my xamarin form app. I watched this video. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DJYLrVNY2ak&t=645s

After all the work, I get permission errors.

Error says:

Unhandled Exception:
Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaPermissionException: Camera permission(s) are required

This code is on MainPage.xaml.cs

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.Media.Abstractions;
using Plugin.Media;
using Plugin.Permissions;
using Plugin.Permissions.Abstractions;

namespace camera
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

            if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable
                || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("No Camera", "No Camera available", "Ok");
                return;
            }

            var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(

                new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                {

                    SaveToAlbum = true,

                });

            if (file == null)
                return;

            PathLabel.Text = file.AlbumPath;

            MainImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                var stream = file.GetStream();
                file.Dispose();
                return stream;


            });




        }
    }
}
```

And this code is on MainPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:camera"
             x:Class="camera.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

        <Button Text="Take a Photo"
                Clicked="Button_Clicked">

        </Button>

        <Image x:Name="MainImage"></Image>
        <Label x:Name="PathLabel"></Label>


    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

The emulator open up fine. When I click "Take a Photo" button. I get permission error.

This is error image. 
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojM8g.png)

Here is link to file. You can download the file and have a look at the error. 
All I want this app to do is take some details, take picture and save picture.
LINK TO FILE
https://contedia-my.sharepoint.com/personal/muhammad_ikram_contedia_com/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?id=%2Fpersonal%2Fmuhammad%5Fikram%5Fcontedia%5Fcom%2FDocuments%2FPhotos%20%282%29%2Ezip&parent=%2Fpersonal%2Fmuhammad%5Fikram%5Fcontedia%5Fcom%2FDocuments&slrid=6f5b859e-50d6-0000-25d8-0fa7f8d3f9ce

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#important-permission-information

Comment: I added this code on the MainActivity.cs. But I still get same permission error.

Comment: do you have Camera enabled in the Android Manifest?

Comment: Yes camera checkbox is ticked as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your MainActivity in Android

`CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);`

Add these lines to your code AsseblyInfo

`[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera", Required = false)]
 [assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera.autofocus", Required = false)]`

Answer (score 0):

I had also exception Camera permission(s) are required. Try add following code to `MainActivity` to `OnCreate()` method. It should ask user for camera permission – you should see alert on device

```
        int requestPermissions;
        string cameraPermission = Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera;

        if (!(ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission(this, cameraPermission) == (int)Permission.Granted))
        {
            ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new String[] { cameraPermission, }, requestPermissions);
        }
```

And put following into android manifest (or check the checkbox)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Maybe following link could also be helpful - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=vswin

Comment: I have placed the above code. I get error "Use of unassigned local variable 'requestPermissions'". Does this variable needs to be declared with any value first.

Comment: I added the above code. I saw the alert message first time, I clicked yes but still it threw same permission error

Comment: I have added link where you can download the file look at error.

Comment: You saw it only once because now it is enabled (you can see it in your device in details about your app). Not sure but try to add  - `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Still showing same error. It is only a demo file. If I can share with you; will you have a chance to look at with your eye.

Comment: Here is download link to file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/lyv6pz7s0t7be74/camera.sln?dl=0

Comment: I am not able to access the link, could you post on github?

Comment: Have you tried this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/lyv6pz7s0t7be74/camera.sln?dl=0

Comment: I downloaded solution but i can see no code, it says - unavailable, the project file or web cannot be found

Comment: Would it be possible if I give you old email address than you can email me your email address. Than I can send the zip folder to to your email. Would be really helpful. My email is ikimuhammed@homtail.com

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: 
Check if the permissions are granted to the app from Settings->Apps->YOUR_APP_NAME->Permissions.

Long answer:
What I noticed is even using the information from the other answers I still get the same error, so I checked the permissions for the app in Settings->Apps->YOUR_APP_NAME->Permissions and I saw that even though I was given camera access to the app when the pop-up appeared, here I still had no permissions granted to the app. So after I turned the permission on from here everything worked fine.